# How to convert the exponential value to normal decimal or without exponent format in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession, nsurlconnectiondelegate

I am getting a exponential value for the expected downloadable size in `NSURLConnectionDelegate`.

It's showing as 1.34597e+08.

Now I am trying to convert the value to 1.3459 using the below code, but with no luck:

```
    self.expectedDownloadSize = Float(response.expectedContentLength)
    let s = self.expectedDownloadSize.description

    let numberFormatter = NSNumberFormatter()
    numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle
    numberFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 4
    var num = numberFormatter.numberFromString(s as String)
    self.expectedDownloadSize = num?.floatValue
```

How can I get the expected size of download?

Comment: You should use the number formatter to convert the number to a string, not the other way around. – Currently you are doing Float -> String -> NSNumber -> Float.

Comment: Btw, `1.34597e+08` would be `134597000`, not `1.34597`.

Comment: Or use NSByteCountFormatter.

Comment: Actually 1.34597e+08 is 134597000.0 let s = 1.34597e+08
print(s)-->134597000.0 ...Returning normal Decimal already ...do i missing something ...here